# split and assign into scalar variables in TCL

Tags: split, tcl

I have a variable and I want to split and assign the chunks to scalar variables.

Example:

```
Variable = vdd_not_gated#7#T
```

I want to assign:

```
net = VDD_NET1
Layer = 7
border = T
```

I tried  following Code in TCL :

```
set variable vdd_not_gated#7#T
set fields [split $variable #]
foreach field $fields {
    lassign $field net layer border
}
puts "$net $layer $border"
```

This doesn't seem to be working. Is there any other way?

Comment: lassign doesnt seem to be working ? How to get the same using normal way?

Comment: what does `puts [package require Tcl]` print?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `foreach`. What you want to do is actually this:

```
lassign [split $variable #] net layer border
```

In older versions of tcl where `lassign` is not available it used to be an idiom to use/abuse foreach:

```
foreach {net layer border} [split $variable #] {}
```

What you were thinking when you wrote that foreach is probably something like this dynamic programming style:

```
foreach varname {net layer border} value [split $variable #] {
    set $varname $value
}
```

Comment: lassign doesnt seem to be working in my tcl  How to get the same using normal way?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need the `foreach` loop here:

```
set variable vdd_not_gated#7#T
set fields [split $variable #]
lassign $fields net layer border
puts "$net $layer $border"
```

What your code was doing was first assigning `vdd_not_gated` to `net` (`layer` and `border` will get empty strings because there is only one element in `field`), then in the next iteration of the loop assigning `7` to `net` (overriding the previous assignment) and last iteration, assigning `T` to `net`.

This is why you also end up with only `T` when you try to print the variables.

Comment: lassign doesnt seem to be working in my tcl .. How to get the same using normal way?

Comment: puts [package require Tcl] is printing 8.4

Comment: @bharathkumar You should consider upgrading to at least 8.5. There is no more support for 8.4 and earlier versions. `lassign` was introduced in Tcl 8.5. You could use slebetman's last code snippet as workaround, or `set` them individually, or use an array.